# Guides on how to drift in Gran Turismo 5

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I've been looking for some great guides on setup and technique, but I can't really seem to find any which aren't for the Prologue version of the game.

Anyone got any ideas, links or tips?

Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're looking for GT5 guides, but I really don't see any.

Here is a great video showing a guy drifting a TVR Tamora on an asphalt track. Notice the white and red bars on the bottom left side of the screen (throttle and brake, respectively). He's being very delicate except for the last turn.

I have had the best luck drifting in a short-ish, high horsepower FR (front-engined, rear wheel drive cars). MR, FF, or 4WD cars simply don't work well for drifting. A softer suspension setting also helps you tell when the rear end of the car is letting go, and allows you a little more time to catch a spin.  Mediocre tires (Sport hard or medium) actually help get the rear end to break loose, like you want.

As far as technique is concerned, you'll see the guy in the video using a LOT of full throttle gas in and throughout the turns; only letting off when he's about to crash or spin the car. Accurate throttle control is the hardest part of drifting. Doing a little 'Scandinavian flick' into each turn really helps to push the rear end of the car out... but don't over do it, or the car will spinout. It take a lot of practice to get that technique down so that you can do it consistently without crashing.

A steering wheel and pedals helps, especially since it give you more accurate throttle control.

Interestingly, finding the exact make and model of car that works best isn't easily predictable. I have successfully used a few ridiculous car that have actually worked quite well (on gravel, at least), like the land-yacht Buick Special. It seems that the sloppy, tail-happy cars that don't work very well for racing (like the TVR and the Buick), work pretty well for drifting.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, good point. I've got an S2000 which I tune for drift, with lots of toe in and hard rear tyres.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I believe ANYTHING can be drifted, at least respectably. FR and 4WD (with a 10:90 to 25:75 ratio) are the best if you're a drifting purist who wish to avoid using the e-brake. If your an e-brake ripper, MR with turbo/supercharger and very close gear ratios are great vehicle since you need that extra "slide" to get around the fact that your car isn't front heavy. In FF vehicles, HARD COMFORT TIRES, LOW POWER, and stubborn suspension seems to be the only way I can get cars to slide without either going crazy or just straightening themsleves out.

Aside from FF vehicles, it is essential that you adjust the LSD. This can be adjusted on every car and can significantly change the driving nature of the vehicle. Acc and Init. Torque should be maxed out while Brake should be minimized. It's easier if you go with that and stick with that although I'd admit I usually use A:60 T:55 B:15 for FR and MR and A:55 T:55 B:10 for 4WD.

If you are tight on money, I recommend instead of maxing out everything as soon as you purchase your drift vehicle you configure it in this order:

LSD, Semi-Racing Fly Wheel, Drive Shaft, balance controller (for 4WD),
Tires (Sport Hards have way too much grip but can be used on 700BHP cars and up),
Transmission (Either 5 gear close or Fully Custom with top speed between 130 and 180),
Suspension (Height Adjustable is just fine - email me for 1 on 1 help),
Weight Reduction (the 1st stage is more than enough),
Engine stage 1,
Turbo/Supercharger,
Anything else after that.

I hope this helps. I'm not currently sitting in front of my system so I apologies for everything that's missing but again, message me and I'll be happy to help.

Inbox me anytime on PSN. l2oI that's a lower-case "L" the number "2" lower-case "O" and capital "I"